# How to parse large xml document with DOM?

Tags: java, xml

I want to parse a xml element that has the following incidents:

- and no xml declaration
- can serve the elements in no particular order

> ```
> <employees>
>    <employee>
>       <details>
>          <name>Joe</name>
>          <age>34</age>
>       </details>
>       <address>
>          <street>test</street>
>          <nr>12</nr>
>       </address>
>    </employee>
>    <employee>
>       <address>....</address>
>       <details>
>          <!-- note the changed order of elements! -->
>          <age>24</age>
>          <name>Sam</name>
>       </details>
>    </employee>
> </employees>
> ```

Output should be a csv:

```
name;age;street;nr
Joe,34,test,12
Sam,24,...
```

Problem: when using event-driven parsers like `stax/sax`, I would have to create a temporary `Employee` bean whose properties I set on each event node, and lateron convert the bean to csv.

But as my xml file is several GB in size, I'd like to prevent having to create additional bean objects for each entry.

Thus I probably have to use plain old `DOM` parsing? Correct my if I'm wrong, I'm happy for any suggestions.

I tried as follows. Problem is that `doc.getElementsByTagName("employees")` returns an empty nodelist, while I'd expect one xml element. Why?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("employees");
for (int i = 0; i < employees.getLength(); i++) {
    Node employee = employees.item(i);
    if (employees.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        NodeList employee = ((Element) employees).getElementsByTagName("employee");
        for (int j = 0; j < employee.getLength(); j++) {
            NodeList details = ((Element) employee).getElementsByTagName("details");

            //the rest is pseudocode
            for (details)
                sb.append(getElements("name").item(0) + ",");
                sb.append(getElements("age").item(0) + ",");    

            for (address) 
                sb.append(getElements("street").item(0) + ",");
                sb.append(getElements("nr").item(0) + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DOM solution is going to use a lot of memory, a SAX/Stax solution is going to involve writing and debugging a lot of code. The ideal tool for this job is an XSLT 3.0 streamable transformation:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <xsl:value-of select="copy-of(.)!(.//name, .//age, .//street, .//nr)" 
                  separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**NOTE**

I originally wrote the select expression as `copy-of(.)//(name, age, street, nr)`. This is incorrect, because the `//` operator sorts the results into document order, which we don't want. The use of `!` and `,` carefully avoids the sorting.

Comment: So I only need the `copy-of` for sorting? Because `select="//name, //age, //street, //nr"` would work as well...

Comment: Without the copy-of, the code isn't streamable. If you don't need streaming then you can write `(.//name, .//age, .//street, .//nr)`. You do need the leading "." (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a StringBuilder but write immediately to the file (Files.newBufferedWriter).

It is not a big deal to manually parse the XML as there does not seem to be a high level of complexity, neither need of XML based validation.

- DOM parsing would build a document object model, just what you would not want.
- Stax needs to build a full employee if sub-elements are unordered.
- So doing reading an employee yourself would not be that different.
- Also the XML seems not to originate from XML writing, and might need to patch XML invalid text, like `&` that should be `&amp;` in XML.

If the XML is valid (you could have a Reader that adds `<?xml ...>` in front), scanning through the XML would be:

```
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader r = f.createXMLStreamReader( ... );
while(r.hasNext()) {
    r.next();
}
```

That easily allows maintaing a Map for employee attributes, started with `<employee>` and ending, being validated and written at `</employee>`.

Comment: So I would have to initialize a `LinkedHashMap` beforehand with the attributes I'm looking for, set them one by one if detected after the starting tag?

Comment: Yes, quite primitively and circumstantial.

Comment: Would this perform better than the `xslt` approach below, on a large dataset?

Comment: I think it is faster and less resource hungry, but whether that is worth the much larger programming effort: try the XSLT first

Comment: The speed of both approaches will be dominated by the XML parsing cost, which is the same in both cases.

Comment: @MichaelKay I upvoted your answer, it should be the first to try. If then it would be slow, one might consider a hand-made solution.